# Reactjs - How to pass an array to a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that creates buttons with information from an array, when the user clicks on the button I want to pass the information from this array to a function, but I'm getting '[Object Object]', how do I pass the array and access the elements in the function?

Function:

```
handleClick (e) {
        const { value } = e.currentTarget
        console.log(value)
    };
```

Component render:

```
render () {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.enrollments.map(item => (
                    <div key={item.id}>
                        <button value={item} onClick={this.handleClick}>
                            {item.enrollment}
                        </button>
                     </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Array passed to map:

```
0: {id: 1, evaluation_flag: false, enrollment: "2019.1", user_id: 2}
1: {id: 2, evaluation_flag: false, enrollment: "2019.2", user_id: 2}
```

In the handleClick function I want to access the values, type: value.id or value.user_id.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create an arrow function if you want, and your code would become:

```
<button value={item} onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e, item)}>
  {item.enrollment}
</button>
```

And then obviously modify the `handleClick` function to accept a second parameter, `item`.

Basically, what the `(e) => handleClick(e, item)` does is create the following function in place:

```
function (e) {
  return handleClick(e, item);
}
```

Comment: Your example is missing a closing paren. `onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e, item)}`

Comment: I exclude the value to stay clean, `<button onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e, item)}>`. Worked very well!!